# Trying to export rigged model to FBX. But it keeps spitting out weird errors

Tags: export, error, .fbx, rigify

I'm trying to export a low poly mesh and its rig as an FBX file. But when I hit export it spits out this error:

```
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 634, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 504, in elem_data_single_int32_array
    return _elem_data_single(elem, name, value, "add_int32_array")
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 451, in _elem_data_single
    getattr(sub_elem, func_name)(value)
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 161, in add_int32_array
    data = array.array(data_types.ARRAY_INT32, data)
  File "E:\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in <genexpr>
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
KeyError: ((nan, nan), 43)

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I have tried reinstalling Blender

Comment: The first (bottom) error suggests there are errors in the UV map. Is it unwrapped? Are there perhaps vertices that aren't unwrapped?

Comment: hold up let me check

Comment: You just saved me! :) and im goinh to kill my texture artist lol

Answer (score 2):

```
 <genexpr>
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
KeyError: ((nan, nan), 43)
```

The first (bottom) error suggests there are errors in the UV map. Try recreating the UV map. The FBX export module requires a valid UV unwrapping for all vertices in the model. Go into the UV Unwrap tab and re-unwrap your model(s).

Comment: I'm having the same problems, but this answer doesn't tell me any information besides it's UV related. I've exported some really messed up UV's before, what exactly in the UV Map would cause this error to occur?

Comment: @JimmyLin, all verts need to have a valid UV coordinate assigned. As I recall, the OP had an object that did not have UVs assigned.

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing an old UV map that came with the mesh.  That UV map had vertices that were outside the boundries so I figured that is what caused the issue.  I didn't know you can import/export UV layouts, I guess we're learning everyday.