# Cant export projext as .fbx

Tags: export

When ever i try and export my project as an .fbx i get this error. Im new to blender so i may have made an error on the model that makes this error appears

[image: Image of the error]

Blender file
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190356/trying-to-export-rigged-model-to-fbx-but-it-keeps-spitting-out-weird-errors

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you *why* this is, but if you go to the Object Data Properties tab, go to UV Maps, and remove the UV map (click the 'minus' button next to it), it will export. I don't know why.