# getting error : location: <unknown location>:-1 when exporting to fbx more then 1 mesh

Tags: mesh, export

when i try to export more than 1 mesh ( in my case 4) to fbx file I'm getting this error :

```
I0905 01:04:14.248471  1848 blender_python.cpp:191] Debug flags initialized to:
CPU flags:
  AVX2       : True
  AVX        : True
  SSE4.1     : True
  SSE3       : True
  SSE2       : True
  BVH layout : BVH8
  Split      : False
CUDA flags:
  Adaptive Compile : False
OptiX flags:
  CUDA streams : 1
OpenCL flags:
  Device type    : ALL
  Debug          : False
  Memory limit   : 0
I0905 01:04:14.427433  1848 device_opencl.cpp:48] CLEW initialization succeeded.
OpenCL error: CL_INVALID_VALUE in __clewGetPlatformInfo(platform_id, 0x0904, sizeof(data), &data, NULL) (C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_lts_283\blender.git\intern\cycles\device\device_opencl.cpp:189)
OpenCL error: CL_INVALID_VALUE in __clewGetDeviceInfo(device_id, 0x1030, sizeof(data), &data, NULL) (C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_lts_283\blender.git\intern\cycles\device\device_opencl.cpp:210)
I0905 01:04:14.619534  1848 device_cuda.cpp:56] CUEW initialization failed: Error opening the library
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.83.5
Build: 2020-08-19 04:10:17 Windows Release
argv[0] = C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\\blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --debug-cycles
argv[3] = --python-expr
argv[4] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\xxx~1.YAN\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
Read prefs: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\config\userpref.blend
read file C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\config\startup.blend
  Version 283 sub 19 date 2020-08-19 06:07 hash c2b144df395f
found bundled python: C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\python
Read blend: C:\Dev\my\blender\projects\car_game\cars_road_test_finall_export1.blend
read file C:\Dev\my\blender\projects\car_game\cars_road_test_finall_export1.blend
  Version 283 sub 19 date 2020-08-19 06:07 hash c2b144df395f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 634, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 504, in elem_data_single_int32_array
    return _elem_data_single(elem, name, value, "add_int32_array")
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 451, in _elem_data_single
    getattr(sub_elem, func_name)(value)
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 161, in add_int32_array
    data = array.array(data_types.ARRAY_INT32, data)
  File "C:\Dev\my\blender\blender-2.83.5-windows64\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in <genexpr>
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
KeyError: ((nan, nan), 36)

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/190356/33589

Comment: tl;dr. Make sure all your objects have valid UV maps.

Comment: well, its simple mesh, how do i make sure it is valid, i can see in blender all good 
how can i verify errors, by the way, if i remove material from mesh export is success 
so the material is the problem