# Blender Exporting as FBX Error

Tags: export, error, .fbx

This is the error message i got when i was trying to export a gun model i made. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 634, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 504, in elem_data_single_int32_array
    return _elem_data_single(elem, name, value, "add_int32_array")
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 451, in _elem_data_single
    getattr(sub_elem, func_name)(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 161, in add_int32_array
    data = array.array(data_types.ARRAY_INT32, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in <genexpr>
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
KeyError: ((nan, nan), 738)

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190360/33589 recreate your UV unwraps and retry

Comment: Relevant ticket https://developer.blender.org/T79775